# How to prove that tangent bundle is a surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

**Question:** Let M be a surface of class $C^k$  and dimension $m\in \mathbb{N}$ and $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ . Consider the following subset
$$TM=\{(x,v)\in \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n; x \in M, v \in T_{x}M\}$$
This subset is called tangent bundle of $M$.

1. Show that $TM$ is a surface of class $C^{k-1}$ and dimension $2m$ in $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$.
2. If $N$ is another surface and $f: M \rightarrow N$ is a function of class $C^k$, define a tangent function
   $T_{f}:TM \rightarrow TN$ given by $T_{f}(x,v)=(f(x), f'(x).v)$ and show that $T_{f}$ is $C^{k-1}$ class.

**My idea:**

1. To show that $TM$ is a surface I need to find a parametrization (or more than one  parametrizations) that is defined in an open set, and such parametrizations cover the subset $TM$ completely. My question is which parametrizatio(s) would I consider?
2. Here, I just would ask you for some hints.

Comment: It seems like your problem statement isn't quite right. What do you mean "and dimension $M \in \mathbb{R}^m$" ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks very much.

Comment: Hey, I think it's still off, dimension should be a natural number, I think you mean $M$ is a surface of dimension $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Of course, in general a manifold $M$ need not be a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Manifolds can be sets of matrices or weirder things like projective spaces...

Comment: Hint: first choose a local parameterization of $M$, then use the induced basis to extend it to a local parameterization of $TM$.

Comment: @James S. Cook. You're really right! I' m sorry. It was my mistake.

Comment: @Kajelad Thanks, I gonna try.